# How to bind the Enabled property of a button in Winforms to the CheckedItems.Count property of a CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, checked, checkedlistbox

I have a CheckedListBox in a form. Each item represents an email message subject of a logged in user.

[image: form]

What I try to achieve is that when only one item is selected, both the Edit and Delete buttons should be enabled, otherwise disabled.

I have tried to use the following event handler after setting the CheckOnClick property to true, but it's not working:

```
private void clbEmailsSubjects_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnEdit.Enabled = btnDelete.Enabled = (clbEmailsSubjects.CheckedItems.Count == 1);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Edit:
I had selected an item, but both buttons were still disabled.

[image]

Now, after selecting the second item they have become enabled:

[image]

The effect seems to be contrary. I think the value of CheckedItems.Count might be updated after the event_handler is executed.

Comment: How specifically does the code you have "not work"?

Comment: What behavior do you observe?

Comment: I have just edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be more correct to use the `ItemCheck` event than the `Click` event (as the click may not have landed on a checkbox).  But either way, the event gets fired before the `Checked` property on the `CheckBox` gets changed, so you can't set the enabled states within either of those event handlers.  You can, however, defer the handling until events are processed using `BeginInvoke`, like this:

```
private void clbEmailsSubjects_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        btnEdit.Enabled = btnDelete.Enabled =
            (clbEmailsSubjects.CheckedItems.Count == 1);
    }));
}
```

Comment: It works even with Click event. Thanks. I had to make an explicit conversion though:         BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                btnEdit.Enabled = btnDelete.Enabled =
                    (clbEmailsSubjects.CheckedItems.Count == 1);
            }));

Comment: I think the last part of your comment got eaten.  But I added an explicit conversion to `MethodInvoker`, which I think is what you were referring to.

Comment: Okay I changed `MethodInvoker` to `Action` to match your comment.  Either should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register for the `ItemCheck` event on your `CheckedListBox`.  Then the following code will give you the desired result:

```
    private void clbEmailsSubjects_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        btnEdit.Enabled = btnDelete.Enabled =
            (clbEmailsSubjects.CheckedItems.Count == 2 && e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked) ||
            (clbEmailsSubjects.CheckedItems.Count == 0 && e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked);
    }
```